# How to display phone number in the flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on simple chat features in my app. I have used OTP login method to do this application. Firebase Authentication is working well in my application. I have already done the code for the simple chat app but I would like to display the user's phone number when they send chat. Example pic added below for better understanding about the need:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../forum/message.dart';

class ForumScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  ForumScreen({required this.email});
  @override
  _ForumScreenState createState() => _ForumScreenState(email: email);
}

class _ForumScreenState extends State<ForumScreen> {
  String email;
  _ForumScreenState({required this.email});

  final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final TextEditingController message = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Farmer's Forum"),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.73,
              child: messages(
                email: email,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: message,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                      hintText: 'message',
                      enabled: true,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 14.0, bottom: 8.0, top: 8.0),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {},
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      message.text = value!;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (message.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      fs.collection('Messages').doc().set({
                        'message': message.text.trim(),
                        'time': DateTime.now(),
                        'email': email,
                       
                      });
                      message.clear();
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send_sharp),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

message.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class messages extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  messages({required this.email});
  @override
  _messagesState createState() => _messagesState(email: email);
}

class _messagesState extends State<messages> {
  String email;
  _messagesState({required this.email});

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _messageStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Messages')
      .orderBy('time')
      .snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _messageStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("something is wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            QueryDocumentSnapshot qs = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            Timestamp t = qs['time'];
            DateTime d = t.toDate();
            print(d.toString());
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: email == qs['email']
                    ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                    : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    child: ListTile(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        qs['email'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 200,
                            child: Text(
                              qs['message'],
                              softWrap: true,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            d.hour.toString() + ":" + d.minute.toString(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How should I read the phone number? I'm not sure how do we related both firebase authentication and cloud firestore.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the information of the phone number you have to provide it to `messages(email)`

Also Widget names (like all class names) should begin with an uppercase

Something like:

```dart
class Messages extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  Messages({required this.email});
  @override
  _MessagesState createState() => _MessagesState(email: email);
}

class _MessagesState extends State<Messages> {
  String email;
  _MessagesState({required this.email});

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _messageStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Messages')
      .orderBy('time')
      .snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _messageStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("something is wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            QueryDocumentSnapshot qs = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            DateTime time = qs['time'].toDate();
            String message = qs['message'];
            String messageEmail = qs['email'];
            String messagePhoneNumber = qs['phoneNumber'];
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: email == messageEmail
                    ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                    : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 300,
                    child: ListTile(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        messageEmail == email ? email : messagePhoneNumber,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 200,
                            child: Text(
                              message,
                              softWrap: true,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            time.hour.toString() + ":" + time.minute.toString(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**As I said, it depends on your provided data if there is a `phoneNumber`**

Comment: It shows bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. I'm not sure why does it not reading the data from firebase authentication if its phone number log in method but if using email login how come it able to read the email?

Comment: @Ramraj Bad State means that you get null on something. Thats why you always nullcheck your data and avoid the exclamation mark.